# Angular2 Is it possible to have several events one after the other

Tags: events, angular

I have a component y which uses directive :

```
 <div makeDroppable (dropped)="getDroppedList($event)">
   <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let task of toAddList" >{{task.id}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

at the end of directives MakeDroppable , an event is emit

```
let data = JSON.parse(ev.dataTransfer.getData('text'));
    this.dropped.emit(data);
```

this event is treated by (dropped)="getDroppedList($event)" (in div) and thus calls getDroppedList of my component.
in this getDroppedList méthod, another event is emit

```
    this.toAddList = <Array<Task>>event;
    console.log('emity event');
    this.toto.emit(this.toAddList);
```

this new event toto is used in another component x where html is

```
<tr *ngFor="let task of tasks" (toto)="removeDroppedList($event)">
```

removeDroppedList is a method defined in x

```
  removeDroppedList(event){
   console.log('this second event')
```

when i execute code, the second event does not seem to be treated because the 'this second event' is never displayed in console.
i put a breakpoint at console.log('this second event'), but 
it never stops

Comment: I'm having trouble following your code hierarchy.  Can you set up a plunker?  It's almost like you are using outputs on elements that aren't angular... ie; <tr (todo)="...  how is <tr> going emit a todo event?   <div makeDroppable (dropped)="... works because dropped is an output on the makeDroppable directive.

Answer (score 0):

Missing " after `tasks` in your template.

Comment: so in your app there is this "? :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the missing " isn't relevant, is there a disconnect with the todo event?  What I mean is, are there more than one todo object being created?  How does component Y have reference to component X's todo event?

Seems like you need a service so both components have reference to the same event object as component X would need to have that as an output and component Y would get it's reference from the service so it can emit a value.

Comment: "What I mean is, are there more than one todo object being created" : yes there is several todo objects. In component y , I have   directives: [x, ...]